# When does a language die?

Tags: language-agnostic

When does a programming language die?

Does it kick the bucket when all the authors of the language cark it?

Comment: Since there has been a lot of discussion about the "death" of Java in recent years, I think this is a valid question.

Comment: why don't we all just GET - A - LIFE!

Comment: Although related to linguistics, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinct_language may be of interest.

Comment: Tell me what you mean by the death of a language, and then I'll tell you "when" it occurs.

Answer (score 9):

With spoken languages, there are a couple definitions: (1) when no one speaks the language, or (2) when no one uses the language as their primary language. You could apply the same criteria to programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on your definition of "dead":

- when it doesn't change/improve anymore
- when no one is using it anymore
- when no one is left who can read it
- when the last document written in that language is gone (otherwise, someone might learn the language from it)

Comment: exactly, the answer to this question varies depending on what each individual's definition of 'dead' is.

Comment: I think that was what the OP was trying to find out.  :-)

Comment: I find it somewhat amusing that if your answer is interpreted as being in chronological order, that implies that at the end there will still be documents (perhaps programs still being run) for which there is nobody alive who can read them.

Comment: @Adam: This wasn't intentional when I wrote it but it makes sense. There is lot of code today which runs but which no one using that code can maintain :)

Answer (score 2):

When nobody uses it. Or you think the people that started the English language are still around? :)

Comment: The languag of the Mayas (Mayan?) was dead for a long time but now, people have started to decode it from stone engravings. Is Mayan dead?

Comment: If nobody uses it, I would say yes. Ok, 10 or 20 people understand it? Good for them, does not changes the fact that nobody else uses it and nobody else want to learn it(problably some scholars might want to). 

http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=dead%20language

Answer (score 1):

Programming language dies, when there are no tools (compilers, libraries) that work on relatively modern platforms. Then nobody can use the language except on vintage platforms.

"When nobody uses it" is not that good definition - how can you *know* that nobody uses it? You can't.

Answer (score 1):

We like to think that a language is dead when it quits being maintained.  However, the reality is that a language dies when there is no software left that is written in it.  As long as that software is still around, somebody will have to maintain it at some point.  I'm not 100% sure on this, but I'd guess that there are few if any languages that have died by this definition.

Answer (score 1):

According to my Latin teacher: Never. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Programming languages can never truly die as long as the compilers and the computers that the programs run on are still in use.

In practice, a programming language starts to die when the authors stop maintaining it, and are effectively dead when people stop writing new programs. It doesn't matter if old programs are still running, since the source code isn't needed to run the programs.

Answer (score 0):

A programming language isn't dead until both the authors stop maintaining it, and the community has moved on to other tools.   For example, Microsoft has declared VB6 to be dead, but there are still many active implementations using VB6.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, in the context of computer languages, a language is truly dead when there are no more problems that someone says "This would be straightforward to solve in "

There are lots of reasons why it is no longer straightforward to use a language:

- no one knows the syntax any more
- the compilers aren't available for the machines you have available
- the compilers don't create object/executable files for the target machine

There are probably others, but those are the ones that spring to mind.

When exactly this occurs is hard to know, but it has happened before, and it will happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Two conditions I'd say:

- No one is choosing that language for new projects.
- There are no plans to update / improve the language.

If both of these are true, then the number of projects that use the language can only go down until it reaches zero.

Whereas if people are still using it to solve new problems, there might be an incentive to improve it at some point. And if someone is still working to improve it, then people might start using it again.

Comment: I'll go with this one. Although indirectly, it covers most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Old languages never die, they only [fade away](http://www.bartleby.com/59/3/oldsoldiersn.html)....